# What is causing a glitch that only shows up in the iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

In the game I'm working on I have a couple of sprites attached to a world node and normally when I run the game the player sprite shows up at the bottom and enemy sprites fall from the top. However sometimes when I use the simulator the sprites that are attached to the world are invisible (or the camera is in a completely different place).

The strange thing is that when the problem occurs I haven't changed anything to the code prior to the problem occurring. I have no idea what is causing this. When I run it on a real device there are no problems. I have already tried resetting the simulator a couple of times. Has anything like this ever happened before?

EDIT:

I kept track of the player's position and the world's position and I've seen three things happening:

```
 player.position.y = nan && world.position.y == -inf
 player.position.y is descending && world.position.y == 0.00000
 player.position.y = 0.00000 && world.position.y = really big number
```

All these things happen when I change the players initial y position. 
Sometimes it just works

Comment: post the code where things go wrong

Comment: I do not know where things go wrong, I've tried debugging, but there is no actual bug since it is a problem with the simulator. I think.

Comment: Always assume the problem is with your code first. It could be as simple as the simulator using a different view size than the device you test on. When you run into the issue, note down what the positions and other properties of affected nodes are, then check how that could be and how that compares when the problem does not occur. Without seeing any code, this could be anything.

Comment: I understand that and since posting this question, without changing any code, that problem has stopped happening. The problem never occurred on a real device in the first place. That lead me to believe that it had something to do with the simulator

Comment: Now for some reason it started again, I think it might be happening because I switch between iOS7 and iOS8 simulators

Comment: The version of iOS does not influence the glitch

Comment: I want to post the code if that will help, but what do you need to see, because I see no direct link between the code and the problem and there are 500-1000 lines of code.

Comment: Are you using random values to  set positions or sizes anywhere in your code, check those to see if they are causing this

Comment: the nan and inf imply that you are dividing a value by zero so check your code for that.

Comment: now it is just working again

Comment: I get that this is kind of a weird post but I don't know what to do